# Creating relationship between two tables using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework

I am working on some CRUD methods for a web app. I am using Entity Framework with SQL Server 2008. In particular, I have two tables that are linked using a cross reference table. It's in the following format:

- Table `Tbl_Plan`

  - `PlanId`
  - `PlanNm`
  - `Active`
- Table `Tbl_Person`

  - `PersonId`
  - `PersonNm`
  - `PersonData`
- Xref table `Xref_PersonPlan`

  - `PersonId`
  - `PersonNm`

Now, when I am creating a new plan I have been trying to link the two together. I'm not sure how. I know it has something to do with referencing the relationship or creating it.

The tables are set up correctly, because I can pull the data just fine once it's created (i.e. my sample entries in SQL Server) but creating the reference is where I am stumped. I tried the following:

```
using (Entities context = new Entities())
{
// TblPlan plan has already been instantiated
plan.TblPersons.Add(person);

context.AddToTblPlans(plan);

context.SaveChanges();
```

But obviously, the `.Add()` isn't what I'm looking for....help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Someone just pointed me in the right direction. I should have waited ten more minutes. I was missing the .AttachTo() - I needed to attach the reference to the context before adding, since it was throwing an InvalidArgumentException.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that many-to-many relationships are not supported in LINQ to SQL the same way they are in Entity Framework and other ORMs, and you'll have to implement the desired behavior yourself.

Take a look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mitsu/archive/2008/03/19/how-to-implement-a-many-to-many-relationship-using-linq-to-sql-part-ii-add-remove-support.aspx) article.  It describes an approach that should work for you.

Comment: I'm sorry, I am using the Entity Frameworks. I'm stupid - not LINQ to SQL.